# Correct spelling of 'mono no aware'

Tags: spelling

Could someone tell me if the phrase 'mono no aware' should be written in a certain way for example hiragana/kanji and if so why? Could you please show me the correct way it should look? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuitive or logical way to know when to use a kanji spelling vs hiragana spelling?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/intuitive-or-logical-way-to-know-when-to-use-a-kanji-spelling-vs-hiragana-spelli)

Answer (score 1):

もののあわれ is the modern way of writing it.

もののあはれ is the old way of writing it if you want an old flavor to it. It's a poetic word, so we like to see it this way, too.

It could be 物の哀れ, but I personally find 物 doesn't look very good; this kanji letter has a feel of breaking the poetic mood to me. :D I prefer ものの哀れ, but I think the hiragana versions are more common and look friendlier.